# Getting only website address from the URI in windows phone

Tags: string, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am working on WP7 project. I have one field named "URL". I want to get only Website address. I want to achieve this in XAML Code.

```
Example :
URL = http://www.techgig.com/skilltest/ASP-Net

Expected Result : http://www.techgig.com 

<TextBlock x:Name="website" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding URL}"   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
```

Is it possible to do this in XAML Code.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider achieving this in your code behind (.cs or .vb). I suggest using "regular expressions" to parse out the URL string to get your desired result. There are many examples of regular expressions with a quick Bing or Google search.

Simple example in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; //needed

namespace SplitingStrings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "http://www.yo.com/stuff/you/donot/want";
            string pattern = "(.com/)";            // Split on .com/ 

            string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
            foreach (string match in substrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(substrings[0] + substrings[1]); //this is what you want

            Console.ReadKey(true);
            // The method writes the following to the console: 
            //    'http://www.yo' 
            //    '.com/' 
            //    'stuff/you/donot/want'
            //    http://www.yo.com/

        }
    }
}
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx)